# Call back when using pre-defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've declared a new function.  Then I'm calling that function later.  How do I run code only if the function I'm calling has completed.
this is my code

```
var callLogin = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(document.getElementById("userLoggedIn") === null) {
            $(".cover").fadeIn(200);
            $(".sixPinInputContainer").fadeIn(200);
            $("#pageBody").css("overflow", "hidden");
            $('.sixPinInput').first().focus();
        };
    })
};
```

Then This is where I call It. The problem is that it's running the .load before it calls my pin container so even if pin is incorrect it runs code.

```
if (startBtn) {
        callLogin() 
        $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateStart.php", {
        roomID: id }, function(data, status) {
            $("#notStartedCount").load("eventHandlersPHP/jobsNotStartedCount.php"); 
            })
    };
```

Comment: Is the function synchronous? If it is, just run code right after.

Comment: define said function to accept a callback that it then calls when it is done. simple.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but how would I do that. I tried adding a callback parameter and then running a callback function in that function but it did the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented pretty well [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp). You could create some sort of action that'll trigger the one function, then it can call the other. Also, [this will probably be a more helpful place for what it is you're trying to do](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/).

-Gonzo